# Passing reference to hardware between methods in custom class

Tags: library, accelerometer, class, magnetometer, object-oriented

I'm a C++ / Arduino newbie, trying to build a custom library for the first time. I created a unit called `CDSensors.cpp`, which has two methods, `SetupSensor` and `ReadSensors`. The sensor is a SparkFun accelerometer/magnetometer.

If there are any errors in the settings, the sensor returns all zeros for compass and accelerometer. If there is no pointer or other connection between the `SetupSensor` and `ReadSensor` methods, the sensor returns all zeros as if it hasn't been setup.

So I'm trying to pass a reference to the sensor library between the methods as shown with the Limu object in the code below. I now get mag data but the accelerometer returns all zeros so something in my object references is messing with the sensor setup? (the accelerometer works ok in the SparkFun demo code, on which my code is based).

Main.ino

```
#include <CDSensors.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SparkFunMPU9250-DMP.h>

CDSensors* LSensors = &CDSensors     (0);
CDSerialPrint* LSerialPrint = &CDSerialPrint (0);
MPU9250_DMP Limu = MPU9250_DMP ();
unsigned long LTimeNow = 0;

struct meas {
  int BUx;
  int acc_x
};

struct meas r;

void setup() {
  LSensors->SetupSensors (Limu);
}

void loop() {
  LSensors->ReadSensors  (Limu, LTimeNow, r.BUx, r.acc_x);
  Serial.print((int) (r.BUx) );
  Serial.print((int) (r.acc_x) );
}
```

CDSensors.h

```
#ifndef CDSensors_h_h
#define CDSensors_h
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SparkFunMPU9250-DMP.h>

class CDSensors {
  public:
    CDSensors(int);
    static void SetupSensors(MPU9250_DMP *imu);
    void ReadSensors (MPU9250_DMP *imu, unsigned long& TimeNow, int&     BUx,int& BUy,int& BUz,int& acc_x,int& acc_y,int& acc_z,int& a0,int& a1,int& a2,int& a3 );
  private:
    int value;
};
#endif
```

CDSensors.cpp

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SparkFunMPU9250-DMP.h>
#include "CDSensors.h"

//MPU9250_DMP imu;
boolean       MPU9250_found = false;
unsigned long TimeNow = 0;
CDSensors::CDSensors(int givenValue) {
  value = givenValue;
}

static void CDSensors::SetupSensors(MPU9250_DMP imu) {
  if (imu.begin() != INV_SUCCESS) {
    while (1) {
      Serial.println("No MPU-9250 found, Check connections");
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
  imu.setSensors(INV_XYZ_ACCEL | INV_XYZ_GYRO | INV_XYZ_COMPASS);
  imu.setGyroFSR(2000);
  imu.setAccelFSR(2);
  imu.setLPF(188);
  imu.setSampleRate(100);
  imu.setCompassSampleRate(100);
}

void CDSensors::ReadSensors(MPU9250_DMP imu, unsigned long& TimeNow, int& BUx, int& acc_x) {
  TimeNow = millis();
  if (imu.dataReady()) {
    imu.update(UPDATE_ACCEL | UPDATE_GYRO | UPDATE_COMPASS);
  }
  BUx = imu.calcMag(imu.mx);
  acc_x = imu.calcAccel(imu.ax);
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason, why you are defining the `MPU9250_DMP` outside of your class and in your main sketch? If you declare it inside of the class as a member variable you can ditch the reference handling

Comment: Try passing the imu parameter by-reference (instead of by-copy), i.e. `MPU9250_DMP& imu`, to the SetupSensors and ReadSensors member functions.

Comment: @ChrisL When it was defined just in CDSensors class ithe sensor returned all zeros. I checked with local serialprint, I suppose somehow the connection between settings and reading data is lost.

Comment: @Nisse sorry tidied indents & typo, resolved your comment I think.

Comment: How die you define it in the class? Did you execute its constructor? If not, that might have been the problem

Comment: Can you post CDSensors.h?   I can't make any sense of `CDSensors*     LSensors      = &CDSensors     (0); CDSerialPrint* LSerialPrint  = &CDSerialPrint (0); `  As the warning says, you are taking the address of a temporary, something that ceases to exist at the end of that line.

Comment: Why are you using classes at all? Are there going to be lots of sensors? If so, making a member function static doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Mikael, new to pointers, I tried MPU9250_DMP* imu and MPU9250_DMP *imu Either way I get  this error - no known conversion for argument 1 from 'MPU9250_DMP' to 'MPU9250_DMP& imu gives the same sub-sensor returning zeros problem.

Comment: @Nick re why classes - reason for moving this bit of code into a seperate .cpp unit is that the program is about to get a lot more complex, plenty of maths and GPRS comms, so the sensor setup/read seemed like a logical chunk to move out of the main.ino I am presuming that the seperate .cpp unit necesitates defining a class?

Comment: No, not at all.

Comment: And if you have changed the code, please post the amended code. We can't debug code we can't see.

Comment: Change `static void SetupSensors(MPU9250_DMP *imu);` to `static void SetupSensors(MPU9250_DMP& imu);` in both source and header file. Do the same change to `ReadSensors`. BW why are you using `static` for `SetupSensors`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are creating instances of these classes correctly. Instead of:

```
CDSensors*     LSensors      = &CDSensors     (0);
CDSerialPrint* LSerialPrint  = &CDSerialPrint (0);            
MPU9250_DMP   Limu = MPU9250_DMP ();
```

How about:

```
CDSensors LSensors (0);
CDSerialPrint LSerialPrint (0);
MPU9250_DMP Limu;
```

I can't get your code to compile, but what I suggest looks a lot simpler.

---

Is your intention here:

```
if (imu.begin() != INV_SUCCESS)
  imu.setSensors(INV_XYZ_ACCEL | INV_XYZ_GYRO | INV_XYZ_COMPASS); 
  imu.setGyroFSR(2000); 
  imu.setAccelFSR(2); 
  imu.setLPF(188); 
  imu.setSampleRate(100); 
  imu.setCompassSampleRate(100);
```

.. to really be:

```
if (imu.begin() != INV_SUCCESS)
  {
  imu.setSensors(INV_XYZ_ACCEL | INV_XYZ_GYRO | INV_XYZ_COMPASS); 
  imu.setGyroFSR(2000); 
  imu.setAccelFSR(2); 
  imu.setLPF(188); 
  imu.setSampleRate(100); 
  imu.setCompassSampleRate(100);
  }
```

The indentation suggests so.

---

> if I understood correctly the class is created on startup with
>
> ```
>        CDSensors* LSensors = &CDSensors (0);
> ```
>
> and is then persistent.

`LSensors` is a persistent *pointer* but `CDSensors (0)` is a temporary object created for the purpose of doing an assignment. For example:

```
int foo = 2 + 3;
```

Now the compiler calculates 2 + 3 (giving 5), assigns that to foo, and then discards the temporarily-calculated 5 used to do the assignment.

In your case `CDSensors (0)` calls the constructor for CDSensors, creating a temporary object. Then the "&" operator takes its address (somewhere on the stack I would guess). This address is copied into LSensors. Then the object is destroyed because its lifetime is over. The compiler even warns you this is happening:

```
 CDSensors*     LSensors      = &CDSensors     (0);
                                                 ^
sketch_may07a:5: error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
```

That means the pointer is now invalid because the underlying object (that it is pointing to) has now been discarded.

---

I've even seen people do something like this quite a bit:

```
     CDSensors LSensors = CDSensors (0);
```

This isn't so bad because pointers aren't involved, but it still involves making a temporary instance of the class, then *copying* that into LSensors, and discarding the original one.

*This* is how to make a new instance of a class:

```
 CDSensors LSensors (0);   // the actual class, not a pointer
```

Or if you want a pointer:

```
 CDSensors * pLSensors;  // a pointer to the class (initially NULL)
```

Then in `setup` you create the instance:

```
pLSensors = new CDSensors (0);
```

Comment: thanks Nick, I tried this variation, it also compiles ok, but still have the same problem with the accl sub-sensor returning zeros

Comment: Add some debugging prints, don't thrash around adding pointers in the hope it will fix things.

Comment: Also see my amended answer.

Comment: Re if (imu.begin() != INV_SUCCESS) sorryyyyyyy typo in code at the top, which is now corrected.

Comment: I wondered if it might be to do with constructors, but if I understood correctly the class is created on startup with CDSensors* LSensors  = &CDSensors (0); and is then persistent. (unlike what i'm used to in delphi where you can type create/destroy all over the place).

Comment: Pointers - right -  I suppose adding pointers saves resources but unlikely to fix a runtime bug.

Comment: See amended answer.

Comment: The third part is misleading. There's no point in talking about "invalid pointer", since the code itself is simply invalid: the language does nog allow applying built-in `&` to a temporary. This is non-compilable. I don't know why the OP keeps guessing whether the object is persistent or not. There's no point is that when the code is simply non-compilable.

Comment: The fourth part is misleading as well. Even in the old "classic" C++ the copy-initialization syntax is immediately interpreted as direct-initialization when the types on the LHS and RHS are the same. There's no temporary object created, there's no copying performed. The constructor arguments are immediately passed to the LHS object. Copy-initialization syntax in this case is repetitive, bulky and unnecessary, but it does not suffer fron inefficiencies you describe in your answer. It is fully equivalent to the "short" version.

Comment: I would add to AnT's comment in this way, why pass the Limu as a parameter to both functions when the constructed object is already global.  Just use `Limu` and remove the parameter in both methods.  If you really wanted to be 'OO' about it, you would pass `Limu` to the constructor. As it is you are passing an `int` that looks like is never used which I don't understand unless there is code missing or is planned for later.